# Cannot load images from public folder

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, image, aws-amplify, public

I store images in public folder, image name is a number from 1 to Image quantity, so I can get image with

```
       <img 
            ref={this.imageRef}
            src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + `/images/${this.props.index}.jpeg`} 
            alt={`image #${this.props.index}`}
        />
```

When I run it on my local npm server images are rendered correclty so I can see them, but when I try to open my gallery from my web site deployed with AWS Amplify, they are not loaded, I see only image alt and image logo.
You can check it out at https://www.diamondcoring.ru/gallery
What's wrong with it ?

Comment: When I take one of the image URLs (eg `https://www.diamondcoring.ru/static/media/26.c2225f92.jpeg`) and put that into the browser address bar, it renders a web page rather than returning an image. Are you sure that the web server is handling images correctly?

Comment: Thanks your your answer, @JohnRotenstein. I'm sure that my react app component is handling images correctly. I tried to store images in public folder and then get them as I have mentioned above, and also import images from src folder with JavaScript within my component. Both ways work correctly on my local machine, but aws web server has some problems with it. I'm new to AWS services so I don't know what is wrong with it. I'll try using S3 bucket to upload images and then get them with JS to render in my app.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why, but the problem was in file extension .jpeg - it is not handled. .jpg or .png work fine